# Which is the best way to control empty fields of the domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I want to know which and where is the best way to control empty or null fields about my domain.

For example, I have a class User which has an Id, a Username, an Email, a Password, a Name, and a Lastname.

And my question is related in where should I check if the Username is empty throw an Exception.

I'm creating an application using NET Core 2.2 and the MVC methodology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a good practice would be to do so in attributes, for example:

```
[Required] 
public string Username {get;set;}
```

I think that what you are after is customer vlidations, attribute base: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#custom-validation

it is more for app specific validation.